# How to get a quick predict value in OLS model?

Tags: python, numpy, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels

How do I get a quick predicted value from my ols model. For example

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

model = sm.ols(formula="price ~ size + year", data=df_c).fit()

model.predict([25,1990]) #(should return predicted price value)
```

How do I get a predicted value when I run model.predict([25,1990]) where 25 is the size and 1990 is the year?

EDIT:

The error I get is 'PatsyError: predict requires that you use a DataFrame when predicting from a model
that was created using the formula api.

The original error message returned by patsy is:
Error evaluating factor: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

Is there a way to just run the simple code of model.predict([25,1990])

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What error do you get when you run `model.predict([25,1990])`?

Comment: thanks. updated it in the question.  But its 'PatsyError: predict requires that you use a DataFrame when predicting from a model
that was created using the formula api.

The original error message returned by patsy is:
Error evaluating factor: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this with the code you have given because you're using `statsmodels.formula.api`. The simplest solution I can provide is to use a quick dictionary:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_c = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3))
df_c.columns = ['price','size','year']
model = sm.ols(formula='price ~ size + year', data=df_c).fit()

model.predict({'size':25,'year':1990})[0]
```

```
-165.2345445772976
```

I created a mock dataframe to show that it works, but all you need is that last line: `model.predict({'size':25,'year':1990})[0]`